# How to send data from a serial device to Google Sheets for data logging

Tags: python, logging, google-sheets, iot

I am trying to send data from my Esmart MPPT Solar Charge Controller to my raspberry pi which will then be sent to Google Sheets for data logging purposes. I have successfully managed to get the required data from my Solar Charge Controller by using the following library and code that I have found on GitHub.

https://github.com/skagmo/esmart_mppt

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import esmart
import time

def handle_data(d):
    
    pv_volt = d['pv_volt']
    bat_volt = d['bat_volt']
    chg_mode = d['chg_mode']
    chg_cur = d['chg_cur']
    load_volt = d['load_volt']
    load_cur = d['load_cur']
    load_power = d['load_power']
    chg_power = d['chg_power']
    bat_temp = d['bat_temp']
    int_temp = d['int_temp']
    soc = d['soc']
    co2_gram = d['co2_gram']
    
    # Correct error in readings
    d['bat_volt'] *= 1.107
    d['load_volt'] *= 1.09
    # Only correct if reading is not zero
    if d['chg_cur']:
        d['chg_cur'] += 1.5

    # chg_power uses uncorrected voltage/current, so recalculate
    actual_power = d['bat_volt']*d['chg_cur']

    print("PV Voltage: %.1f V" % (d['pv_volt']))
    print("Battery: %.1f V" % (d['bat_volt']))
    print("Charging (status: %s): %.1f A, %.1f W" % (esmart.DEVICE_MODE[d['chg_mode']], d['chg_cur'], 
    actual_power))
    print("Discharging: %.1f V, %.1f A, %.1f W" % (d['load_volt'], d['load_cur'], d['load_power']))
    print("Load Voltage: %.1f V" %(d['load_volt']))
    print("Load Current: %.1f A" %(d['load_cur']))
    print("Charge Power: %.1f W" %(d['chg_power']))
    print("Load Power: %.1f W" %(d['load_power']))
    print("Battery Temperature: %.1f °C" %(d['bat_temp']))
    print("Internal Temperature: %.1f °C" %(d['int_temp']))
    print("State of Charge: %.1f %%" %(d['soc']))
    print("CO2 Reduction: %.1f g" %(d['co2_gram']))

e = esmart.esmart()
e.open("/dev/ttyUSB0")
e.set_callback(handle_data)

while 1:
    e.tick()
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

The output of the code:

```
PV Voltage: 0.1 V
Battery: 13.6 V
Charging (status: IDLE): 0.0 A, 0.0 W
Discharging: 0.0 V, 0.0 A, 0.0 W
Load Voltage: 0.0 V
Load Current: 0.0 A
Charge Power: 0.0 W
Load Power: 0.0 W
Battery Temperature: 0.0 °C
Internal Temperature: 32.0 °C
State of Charge: 68.0 %
CO2 Reduction: 0.0 g
```

This is the code that I use to send data from my sensors to Google Sheets:

```
#import libraries
from __future__ import print_function  
from googleapiclient.discovery import build  
from httplib2 import Http  
from oauth2client import file, client, tools  
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials  
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO,time
import Adafruit_DHT


"""acquire spreadsheet ID at the URL of the spreadsheet
which are enclosed in *//* e.g https://docs.google.com
/spreadsheets/d/1KqWlsVCJgGjLFb7YKfrOnqHpl3n3BWGblOXsV22IGOQ/
edit#gid=0"""

#declaring spreadsheet ID
MY_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1KqWlsVCJgGjLFb7YKfrOnqHpl3n3BWGblOXsV22IGOQ'

#defining update_sheet function
def update_sheet(sheetname, humidity1, temperature1, humidity2, temperature2, humidity3, temperature3):
    
    
    """acquire .json file from setting up credentials by following
    this tutorial: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#service-account"""
    
    #authentication 
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    
    """for the next line of code, enter the path of the file where the .json file was acquired from the above linked
       tutorial e.g /home/pi/gspread/Hydroponics-0b1b25110de8.json *note: the .json file
       can be placed anywhere as long as the path is declared as shown below*"""
    
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/pi/hydroponicsmonitoring/Hydroponics-0b1b25110de8.json',SCOPES)
    
    #authorization
    service = build('sheets','v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    
    #call the sheets API, append the next row of sensor data
    """values" is the array of rows that we are updating, it is a single row"""
    
    values = [[ str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'Humidity at Level 1', humidity1, 'Temperature at Level 1', temperature1,
                'Humidity at Level 2', humidity2, 'Temperature at Level 2', temperature2,
                'Humidity at Level 3', humidity3, 'Temperature at Level 3', temperature3]]
    body = {'values':values}
    
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=MY_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range=sheetname + '!A1:G1',
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS',
        body=body).execute()
   
def humidtemp1():
    humidity1, temperature1 = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,4)
    return ((humidity1),(temperature1))

humidity1, temperature1 = humidtemp1()
print ('Humidity at Level 1: %.2f %%rH' % humidity1)
print ('Temperature at Level 1: %.2f Celcius' % temperature1)

def humidtemp2():
    humidity2, temperature2 = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,26)
    return ((humidity2),(temperature2))

humidity2, temperature2 = humidtemp2()
print ('Humidity at Level 2: %.2f %%rH' % humidity2)
print ('Temperature at Level 2: %.2f Celcius' % temperature2)

def humidtemp3():
    humidity3, temperature3 = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,19)
    return ((humidity2),(temperature2))

humidity3, temperature3 = humidtemp3()
print ('Humidity at Level 3: %.2f %%rH' % humidity3)
print ('Temperature at Level 3: %.2f Celcius' % temperature3)

update_sheet("Sheet1", humidity1, temperature1, humidity2, temperature2, humidity3, temperature3)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

However, when i try to integrate the code above with the code I use for Google Sheets data logging I get an error that I don't know how to resolve.

```
#import libraries
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function  
from googleapiclient.discovery import build  
from httplib2 import Http  
from oauth2client import file, client, tools  
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials  
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO,time
import Adafruit_DHT
import struct, time, serial, socket, requests
import json
#library for the MPPT Solar Charge Controller that was found on GitHub
import esmart


"""acquire spreadsheet ID at the URL of the spreadsheet
which are enclosed in *//* e.g https://docs.google.com
/spreadsheets/d/1KqWlsVCJgGjLFb7YKfrOnqHpl3n3BWGblOXsV22IGOQ/
edit#gid=0"""

#declaring spreadsheet ID
MY_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1KqWlsVCJgGjLFb7YKfrOnqHpl3n3BWGblOXsV22IGOQ'



#defining update_sheet function
def update_sheet(sheetname, pv_volt):
    
    
    """acquire .json file from setting up credentials by following
    this tutorial: https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#service-account"""
    
    #authentication 
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    
    """for the next line of code, enter the path of the file where the .json file was acquired from the above linked
       tutorial e.g /home/pi/gspread/Hydroponics-0b1b25110de8.json *note: the .json file
       can be placed anywhere as long as the path is declared as shown below*"""
    
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/pi/hydroponicsmonitoring/Hydroponics-0b1b25110de8.json',SCOPES)
    
    #authorization
    service = build('sheets','v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    
    #call the sheets API, append the next row of sensor data
    """values" is the array of rows that we are updating, it is a single row"""
    
    values = [[ str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'PV Voltage', pv_volt]]
    
    body = {'values':values}
    
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=MY_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range=sheetname + '!A1:G1',
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS',
        body=body).execute()

  
STATE_START = 0
STATE_DATA = 1

REQUEST_MSG0 = b"\xaa\x01\x01\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x1e\x32"
LOAD_OFF = b"\xaa\x01\x01\x02\x04\x04\x01\x00\xfe\x13\x38"
LOAD_ON = b"\xaa\x01\x01\x02\x04\x04\x01\x00\xfd\x13\x39"

DEVICE_MODE = ["IDLE", "CC", "CV", "FLOAT", "STARTING"]



def __init__(self):
    self.state = STATE_START
    self.data = []
    self.callback = False
    self.port = ""
    self.timeout = 0

def __del__(self):
    self.close()

def set_callback(self, function):
    self.callback = function

def open(self, port):
    self.ser = serial.Serial(port,9600,timeout=0.1)
    self.port = port


def send(self, pl):
    self.ser.write(self.pack(pl))

def parse(self, data):
    for c in data:
        if (self.state == STATE_START):
            if (c == 0xaa):
                # Start character detected
                self.state = STATE_DATA
                self.data = []
                self.target_len = 255
                #else:
                #print c
                
        elif (self.state == STATE_DATA):
            self.data.append(c)
            
            # Received enough of the packet to determine length
            if (len(self.data) == 5):
                self.target_len = 6 + self.data[4]
                
                # Received whole packet
                if (len(self.data) == self.target_len):
                    self.state = STATE_START
                    #print " ".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in self.data)
                    
                    # Source 3 is MPPT device
                    if (self.data[2] == 3):
                        msg_type = self.data[3]
                        
                        # Type 0 packet contains most data
                        if (self.data[3] == 0):
                                    fields = {}
                                    fields['chg_mode'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[7:9], byteorder='little')
                                    fields['pv_volt'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[9:11], byteorder='little') / 10.0
                                    fields['bat_volt'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[11:13], byteorder='little') / 10.0
                                    fields['chg_cur'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[13:15], byteorder='little') / 10.0
                                    fields['load_volt'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[17:19], byteorder='little') / 10.0
                                    fields['load_cur'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[19:21], byteorder='little') / 10.0
                                    fields['chg_power'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[21:23], byteorder='little')
                                    fields['load_power'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[23:25], byteorder='little')
                                    fields['bat_temp'] = self.data[25]
                                    fields['int_temp'] = self.data[27]
                                    fields['soc'] = self.data[29]
                                    fields['co2_gram'] = int.from_bytes(self.data[33:35], byteorder='little')
                                    
                                    self.callback(fields)

def tick(self):
    try:
        while (self.ser.inWaiting()):
            self.parse(self.ser.read(100))
            
            # Send poll packet to request data every 5 seconds
            
            if (time.time() - self.timeout) > 5:
                self.ser.write(REQUEST_MSG0)
                self.timeout = time.time()
                #time.sleep(0.5)
                #self.ser.write(LOAD_OFF)
                
    except IOError:
        print("Serial port error, fixing")
        self.ser.close()
        opened = 0
        while not opened:
            try:
                self.ser = serial.Serial(self.port,38400,timeout=0)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                if self.ser.read(100):
                    opened = 1
                
                else:
                    self.ser.close()
            
            except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.ser.close()
                print("Error fixed")


pv_volt = parse

def handle_data(d):
    
    pv_volt = d['pv_volt']
    bat_volt = d['bat_volt']
    chg_mode = d['chg_mode']
    chg_cur = d['chg_cur']
    load_volt = d['load_volt']
    load_cur = d['load_cur']
    load_power = d['load_power']
    chg_power = d['chg_power']
    bat_temp = d['bat_temp']
    int_temp = d['int_temp']
    soc = d['soc']
    co2_gram = d['co2_gram']
    
    # Correct error in readings
    d['bat_volt'] *= 1.107
    d['load_volt'] *= 1.09
    # Only correct if reading is not zero
    if d['chg_cur']:
        d['chg_cur'] += 1.5

    # chg_power uses uncorrected voltage/current, so recalculate
    actual_power = d['bat_volt']*d['chg_cur']
    
    print("PV Voltage: %.1f V" % (d['pv_volt']))
    print("Battery Voltage: %.1f V" % (d['bat_volt']))
    print("Charging (status: %s): %.1f A, %.1f W" % (esmart.DEVICE_MODE[d['chg_mode']], d['chg_cur'], actual_power))
    print("Discharging: %.1f V, %.1f A, %.1f W" % (d['load_volt'], d['load_cur'], d['load_power']))
    print("Load Voltage: %.1f V" %(d['load_volt']))
    print("Load Current: %.1f A" %(d['load_cur']))
    print("Charge Power: %.1f W" %(d['chg_power']))
    print("Load Power: %.1f W" %(d['load_power']))
    print("External Temperature: %.1f °C" %(d['bat_temp']))
    print("Internal Temperature: %.1f °C" %(d['int_temp']))
    print("State of Charge: %.1f %%" %(d['soc']))
    print("CO2 Reduction: %.1f g" %(d['co2_gram']))




e = esmart.esmart()
e.open("/dev/ttyUSB0")
e.set_callback(handle_data)

update_sheet("Sheet1", pv_volt)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

*note: In this code, I am only trying to get the value of the pv_volt to be sent to Google Sheets

The error that I get from running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/hydroponicsmonitoring/esmarttest2.py", line 220, in <module>
    update_sheet("Sheet1", pv_volt)
  File "/home/pi/hydroponicsmonitoring/esmarttest2.py", line 60, in update_sheet
    body=body).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 1022, in method
    headers, actual_path_params, actual_query_params, body_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 162, in request
    body_value = self.serialize(body_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 275, in serialize
    return json.dumps(body_value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Perhaps it's one of the arguments. Can you show what you get if you print the arguments you're passing to `append` in line 55?

Comment: @Calculuswhiz [the printed arguments when I use it with my sensors](https://imgur.com/6WgC5Po)

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I think the error is most likely due to the code in line 173. Since I'm very new to python I don't really know how else to define `pv_volt` to be used in the `update_sheet` function.

Comment: `Object of type function is not JSON serializable` says that that what you're trying to send (`pv_volt`) is a function ("of type function"), and update_sheet can't convert it to JSON (with json.dumps(...)). It looks like `pv_volt` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*You can't send functions as a part of the body in a request to Google Sheets API.*

### Explanation

You are assigning `pv_volt` as a function here:

```
#...CODE
            except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.ser.close()
                print("Error fixed")


pv_volt = parse # <-- HERE

def handle_data(d):
    
    pv_volt = d['pv_volt']
    bat_volt = d['bat_volt']

#... CODE
```

The calling function starts here:

```
e = esmart.esmart() # <-- You are using the esmart library here and not your functions
e.open("/dev/ttyUSB0")
e.set_callback(handle_data) # <-- This will not be called, 'pv_volt' is still a function

# tick() function should be called if you mean to get new data or use it
# in a loop in order to make polling requests.
# e.tick()

update_sheet("Sheet1", pv_volt) # <-- HERE
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Then in the `def update_sheet(sheetname, pv_volt):` function

```
#... CODE
    values = [[ str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'PV Voltage', pv_volt]]
    
    body = {'values':values} # <-- There's a function in the body request
    
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
        spreadsheetId=MY_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range=sheetname + '!A1:G1',
        valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
        insertDataOption='INSERT_ROWS',
        body=body).execute() # <-- Make a request with a function in the body

#... CODE
```

### Summary

In order to refresh your `pv_volt` variable you should call the [tick function](https://github.com/skagmo/esmart_mppt/blob/master/esmart.py#L90) for getting new data from your device and then make the Google Sheets request by using `update_sheet("Sheet1", pv_volt)`.